# Change input text field value by radio checked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to display total price with sum by values of subtotal and shipping cost, But my code can't get subtotal value on input text field.

Example :

```
Subtotal: 200
Shipping A: 100 (checked)
Shipping B: 200
Totalprice: 300

or

Subtotal: 200
Shipping A: 100 
Shipping B: 200 (checked)
Totalprice: 400
```

Here's my code on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fp0s5d88/).

Comment: Put your code up in the question as some of the users can't access external services such as jsfiddle.

Comment: You might want to include the code in the question rather than a link to jsfiddle, it's much more useful for other users. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Use `.val()` to set value not `.html()`

Also note, `$(".subtotal")` will return `jQuery` wrapped object but we need value of that element hence Use `parseInt($(".subtotal").val())` to get parsed value of that input field. Use `.text()` instead of `.html()` if you wish to get `text` value than `html`

Try this:

```js
function updateCosts() {
  var totals = parseInt($(".subtotal").val());
  $.each($('#content input[type=radio]:checked'), function() {
    totals += parseInt($.trim($(this).next('.shippingcost').text()));
  });
  $('#totalPrice').val(totals);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#content input[type=radio]').change(updateCosts);
  //_____________________________^^^^^^^_^^^^^^^^^^^
  //Use change event instead of click, handler can be attached this way
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Subtotal:
<input type="text" value="200" name="subtotal" class="subtotal">
<div id="content">
  A:
  <input type="radio" name="shippingcost" checked> <span class="shippingcost"> 100 </span> B:
  <input type="radio" name="shippingcost"> <span class="shippingcost"> 200 </span>
</div>
Total price:
<input type="text" name="totalprice" id="totalPrice">
```

[Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/fp0s5d88/2/)

Comment: Thank you so much, But it possible if I want to get value from `value="200"` code it will be like `var totals = parseInt($("input=[value]").val());` right?

Comment: Yes..But if it is the unique element then go with the id..`$(#ID_SELECTOR).val()`

Comment: Oh, Thank you so much, :)